# 2 switches in one box in bathroom

Tags: switch, bathtub

I have 2 switches in bathroom in on box.  1 switch controls the light and the other switch controls the bathroom fan.  I believe power comes in to light switch then to fan switch.  How do I change out the 2nd switch?

Comment: You want to replace the switch? Do you know what type of switch you want instead?  How comfortable are you with electrical work?

Comment: I replaced the fan motor and have power at the switch but no power at the fan motor plug.  I think it all goes back to work down when I had a pocket door installed and the handyman had to relocate the switch box.  Bathroom light, not co-located with fan, but both switches in same box, works.

Answer (score -1):

use a non contact voltage detector (its a small "pen" like instrument that when put near power will beep) to confirm which switch the power comes from. black will be your power wire, white is neutral and red is for the switch. (any one will zap you if not careful)

switch the breaker to the OFF position (Make sure you've got the right one!!) and replacing the switch is as easy as unscrewing the screws and reattaching the wires in their corresponding positions.

Comment: The OP never mentioned what color wires are present, so you're guessing based on typical convention. That could be dangerous.  Second. Black is not always power, white is not always neutral, and red is not always switched hot. Again you're making dangerous assumptions.